# Play Framework 2.3 startup scripts for systemd?

Tags: centos, systemd

We're upgrading to Play 2.3.x (which uses activator) and CentOS 7 (which uses systemd). Previously on CentOS 6 we used [this SysV init script](https://gist.github.com/jlsuarezs/5461336#file-init-d) to start/stop/restart our various Play applications. Is there a similar method for systemd now that most distros have migrated to it?

Comment: systemd units are _very_ easy to write. What have you tried?

Comment: This is the closest I've found: https://gist.github.com/dkhenry/4470375 However if they are as easy to create as you say, maybe I'll google around for a tutorial on that